# SQL Server dynamic Order By in query, different data types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

In **SQL Server 2000**

I have a query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.COLUMN1, B.COLUMN2 FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE 
A.KEY_ID = B.FK_ID

ORDER BY CASE @ORDER_NAME
         WHEN 'COL1' THEN COLUMN1
         WHEN 'COL2' THEN COLUMN2
         ELSE
         COLUMN2
         END ASC
```

Here A.COLUMN1 is varchar(50) and B.COLUMN2 is datetime. This query works perfectly when value of @ORDER_NAME is 'COL2' i.e. when order by is of type datetime but when I used 'COL1' it gives error 'Syntax error converting datetime from character string.'

I think that this is because SQL Server is trying to convert all the columns to datetime type. But I can't find an alternative syntax to dynamically sort the columns. EXEC is out of question due to performance issues

I need to mention that I am trying to avoid branching otherwise the above can be done by ane IF ELSE clause also.

Comment: Please don't use all caps (in the title).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Version without any data type conversion issues:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        A.COLUMN1, 
        B.COLUMN2 
FROM    TABLEA A, 
        TABLEB B 
WHERE   A.KEY_ID = B.FK_ID
ORDER BY 
        CASE @ORDER_NAME WHEN 'COL1' THEN COLUMN1 ELSE NULL END,
        CASE @ORDER_NAME WHEN 'COL2' THEN COLUMN2 ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: this also works but only post is allowed to be marked as answer

Comment: @devanalyst: sure, even though I still believe that my solution is better [:)  - would not have posted it otherwise]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
IF @ORDER_NAME = 'COL1'
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT A.COLUMN1, B.COLUMN2 FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE A.KEY_ID = B.FK_ID
    ORDER BY COLUMN1 ASC
END

ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT A.COLUMN1, B.COLUMN2 FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE A.KEY_ID = B.FK_ID
    ORDER BY COLUMN2 ASC
END
```

Comment: I know branching like above will work but I am trying to avoid branching because the actual query has many different possible 'order by' columns

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.COLUMN1, B.COLUMN2, 
    CASE @ORDER_NAME
        WHEN 'COL1' THEN COLUMN1
        ELSE CONVERT(COLUMN2,  --convert to nvarchar in a way that orders properly, cant remember off the top of my head 
    END SortCol
FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B
WHERE A.KEY_ID = B.FK_ID
ORDER BY SortCol ASC
```

update:

Actually you could probably convert the date to an varchar in you query and it would work, I've just done it like the above before, when the sort columns where coming from an xquery expression so posted it like that.

Comment: Do you mean like 
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),COLUMN2,102) AS SOMECOL FROM SOMETABLE ORDER BY SOMECOL.
But I doubt that conversion to nvarchar will change the way the column is ordered

Comment: if you convert the date column to a string and then order by it, the format **WILL** alter the order. you need to format it like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm (format 121) if not and you format it like mm/dd/yyyy all the january dates from any year are first.

Comment: You just need to convert so that it is YYYYMMDD... and will order properly

Answer (score 0):

convert them to all to varchar:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.COLUMN1, B.COLUMN2 FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE 
A.KEY_ID = B.FK_ID

ORDER BY CASE @ORDER_NAME
         WHEN 'COL1' THEN CONVERT(varchar(nn),COLUMN1)
         WHEN 'COL2' THEN CONVERT(varchar(23),COLUMN2,121)
         ELSE
         CONVERT(varchar(23),COLUMN2,121)
         END ASC
```

you could then even sort by multiple columns then, which is good when you have many similar values in the sort by column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.COLUMN1, B.COLUMN2 FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B WHERE 
A.KEY_ID = B.FK_ID

ORDER BY CASE @ORDER_NAME
         WHEN 'COL1' THEN CONVERT(varchar(nn),COLUMN1)+CONVERT(varchar(23),COLUMN2,121)
         WHEN 'COL2' THEN CONVERT(varchar(23),COLUMN2,121)+RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',nn)+CONVERT(varchar(nn),COLUMN1),nn)
         ELSE CONVERT(varchar(23),COLUMN2,121)+RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',nn)+CONVERT(varchar(nn),COLUMN1),nn)
         END ASC
```

Comment: converting a datetime column to varchar seems to change the way it is ordered

Comment: duh, forgot to put in format style 121: _yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm_, try it now, should work